# Finding functions of a sample that converge to a desired constant

Tags: probability, convergence-divergence, poisson-distribution

> Let there be a n-sized sample (iid r.v.'s), $\{X_{n}\}_{n \geq 1}$, from a r.v. $X \sim \operatorname{Poisson}(\lambda)$. Knowing that $\bar{X} \xrightarrow[]{P} \lambda$, find a function $T(.)$ for which $T(X_{1},...,X_{n}) \xrightarrow[]{P} e^{\lambda}$  holds. Also find a $G(.)$ for which $G(X_{1},...,X_{n}) \xrightarrow[]{P} \mathbb{P(X=0)}+\mathbb{P(X=1)}$ holds.

My thoughts are:

We know  that 
\begin{align}
\lim_{n \xrightarrow[]{} \infty} P(\lvert \bar{X}-\lambda\rvert > \epsilon) &=0 \\
\mathbb{P}(X=0)+\mathbb{P}(X=1) &= e^{-\lambda} + \lambda e^{-\lambda}
\end{align}
And the conditions for the desired convergences are:
\begin{align}
\lim_{n \xrightarrow[]{} \infty} P(\lvert T(X_{1},...,X_{n})-e^{\lambda}\rvert > \epsilon) &=0\\
\lim_{n \xrightarrow[]{} \infty} P(\lvert G(X_{1},...,X_{n})-(e^{-\lambda} + \lambda e^{-\lambda})\rvert > \epsilon) &=0
\end{align}

I'd like to know if we can choose:
\begin{align}
T(X_{1},...,X_{n}) = \bar{X}-\lambda +e^{\lambda} \\
G(X_{1},...,X_{n}) = \bar{X}-\lambda +e^{-\lambda} + \lambda e^{-\lambda}
\end{align}

Because then the limits would turn into the first one that we know it's equal $0$, fulfilling the conditions.

|EDIT|

I found the following theorem:

> The Continuous Mapping Theorem:
>   Let $Xn$ and $X$ be random variables and $g$, a continuous function.
>   If $Xn \xrightarrow[]{P} X$, then $g(Xn) \xrightarrow[]{P} g(X)$.

Therefore it would be simply:

\begin{align}
T(X_{1},...,X_{n}) = e^{\bar{X}} \\
G(X_{1},...,X_{n}) = \lambda e^{\bar{X}} + e^{\bar{X}}
\end{align}

Is this a fine solution?  Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't understand what you're trying to do. The highlighted part at the top ends with two sentences that postulate something. It doesn't seem to contain anything to be proved or determined.

Comment: (Note that you can get proper formatting for $\lim$ by using the command `\lim`. More generally, for operators that don't have a command of their own, you can use `\operatorname{name}`.)

Comment: @joriki the excercise demands you to create a function that converges in the way shown above. English isn't my primary language, sorry. Rephrasing tha question: "Create a $T(.)$ and a $G(.)$ that, respectively, converge in probability to $e^{\lambda}$ and $\mathbb{P}(X=0)+\mathbb{P}(X=1)$"

Comment: I see. I think "find" would be the verb usually used for that in a mathematical context. By the way the title still says "postulating".